# change comment form container to textarea

Tags: 7, forms, comments

How to remove the red section in next image (comment form)?

[image: gh]

I have try change the type to textarea, but on submit the form a blank page appears.

```
function THEME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    $form['comment_body']['#type'] = 'textarea';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the field plain text in the comment body field settings.

e.g:

http://example.com/admin/structure/types/manage/article/comment/fields/comment_body

> "Text processing" > "Plain text"

Comment: is possible convert ENTERS (news lines) in paragraphs?

Comment: To convert new lines to <br /> you may need to use a theme function and the [nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) function

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all that text entirely by using the "better formats" module. https://drupal.org/project/better_formats  I think that is what you're after, here. But you'll also just want to be cautious that you're setting a proper input format for people here for what they're doing. For comments, you'll likely want it to be a very limited HTML format, or a Plain Text format.